# How can I overlay text on a videocapture with python opencv and pillow

Tags: python, opencv

I started by showing text on my video capture with the .putText() function. But I couldn't use a custom truetype font. So I looked it up. And I found out that I could do what I want with pillow. But it just doesn't work. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from datetime import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%D: %H:%M:%S")

    fontpath = "./Roboto-Light.ttf"     
    font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 22)
    img_pil = Image.fromarray(frame)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)

    draw.text((120,660),  current_time, font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 48), fill = (168,98,0,0)) # Hour and Minute
    
    cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.setWindowProperty('frame', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
  

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


´´´
```

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: I'm on windows.

Comment: use OpenCV's `putText`. no need for PIL at all. OpenCV also has a truetype package in addition to the basic vector fonts of putText.

Comment: also you must check if ret is true from cap.read(), and you need to check if cap.isOpened() right after creating the VideoCapture

Comment: As I said, I would like to use a custom font

Comment: if you need to use PIL, *do* convert the PIL image back into a numpy array.

Comment: Anddd actually everything works, the problem is the fact that the code above doesn't display any text. And I don't get any errors

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: Are you sure that the path to your font file is correct?

Comment: Yupp 100% sure.